# Check if cell is empty without a direct cell reference

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A              B              C
1         1
2        =IF(A1="";"";A1+1)
3        =IF(A2="";"";A2+1)
4        =IF(A3="";"";A3+1)
5        =IF(A4="";"";A4+1)
6        =IF(A5="";"";A5+1)
```

In column A I have formulas refering to the cell above the cell to check if this cell is empty. In case the cell above is empty the actually cell should also be empty.

Now I want to make the first part of this formula independent of a direct cell reference. Something like `If(ROW()-1="";"";A1+1)`

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Theoretically, you are doing this already. In R1C1-style your formula looks like: `=IF(R[-1]C="","",R[-1]C+1)`. Which is nothing less then: `IF ([the cell 1 row over my row in the same column] = "" THEN "" ELSE [the cell 1 row over my row in the same column] + 1)`... just the A1-Style looks different... also copying a cell from A2 which has A1 in the formula will change the A1 in it. So if copied to C3 it will check C2 then. But you also could use the real [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `INDIRECT` is a volatile function (it will be calculated every time a change occured, even no change to its parent has been done)